# "b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380?

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose, dockerfile

> Client Error: Bad Request ("b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java": stat /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: no such file or directory: unknown'")

this my error ,I cann't fix this ,when I use docker-compose and docker
my version

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.12
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        48a66213fe
 Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:45:44 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.12
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       48a66213fe
  Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:44:15 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.12
  GitCommit:        7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683

docker compose version
docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown
docker-py version: 4.1.0
CPython version: 3.8.10
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

# Install maven
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y maven

WORKDIR /code

# Prepare by downloading dependencies
ADD pom.xml /code/pom.xml
RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve", "-U"]
RUN ["mvn", "verify"]

# Adding source, compile and package into a fat jar
ADD src /code/src
RUN ["mvn", "package", "-DskipTest=True", "-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true", "-Dmaven.test.skip=true", "--offline"]

EXPOSE 4458
# CMD ["ls", "-la", "target/"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java", "-jar", "target/pbft-jar-with-dependencies.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  node_java:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose.node-java.yml
      service: node
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      NODE_DEBUG: "False"
```

docker-compose.node-java.yml

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  node:
    build: .
    environment:
      NODE_PORT: 4458
    command: ["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"]
    # restart: "unless-stopped"
    # stdin_open: true
  node-pi:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ARM.Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_PORT: 4458
```

Any suggestion will help !!!

thank you very much

Comment: I think it complains about a missing OpenJDK 8. You probably need to install OpenJDK in your container: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

Comment: Maybe the image you are cloning from has some problem with the OpenJDK installation? Or maybe the path to the JDK is different from the one you used in your entry point: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`. Run the plain image `openjdk:8-jdk` and find out where java is: `ls /usr/lib/jvm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the path to the java executable in the image is different than the one you used.
Can you try and replace the path in your DOCKERFILE like so?

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java", "-jar", "target/pbft-jar-with-dependencies.jar"]
```

I used the following procedure to find that out:

```bash
docker pull openjdk:8-jdk
docker run openjdk:8-jdk
docker container ls -a

mkdir -p /tmp/snapshot
cd /tmp/snapshot
docker export 7778d9fa6ce9> snapshot.tar
tar -xvf snapshot.tar
find . -type f -name java
```

Answer (score 0):

modify  Old java site

to this

```
/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java
```

it is error

second
I fix this using old version docker and docker-compose

modify version :

Since my project is 2017, I choose the old version of docker and the docker compose version close to 2017

---

detail version

```
 docker-ce | 5:18.09.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
```

---

docker compose

https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.16.1

1.16.1